# ruby: remove a value in an array that is in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: [9, 8, 7]}
```

I need to write a method that given a pair `key` and `value`, removes the occurrences of such couple from the hash.

for example, if I pass the couple `(:a, 1)` I obtain the hash:

```
a = { b: 2, c: [9, 8, 7]}
```

if I pass the couple `(:c, 8)` I obtain the hash:

```
a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: [9, 7]}
```

if I pass the couple `(:a, 3)` I obtain the (unchanged) hash:

```
a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: [9, 8, 7]}
```

I'm not sure how to do this, here's what I got so far:

```
  def remove_criterion (key, value)
    all_params = params.slice(key)
    if all_params[key].class == Array

    else
      params.except(key)
    end
  end
```

which obviously is incomplete.

thanks for any help,

Comment: What happens if you have hash `{a: [[1], 2]}`, and give key `:a` and value `[1]`? Is `[1]` supposed to be deleted from `[[1], 2]` because it is an element of it, or is it supposed to retain because `[1]` is not `[[1], 2]`? Your question is not clear.

Comment: `{a: [[1], 2]}` makes no sense in my context, so any behaviour is fine for this case. It just won't reasonably happen.

Comment: So what can appear in your hash and what cannot? You haven't mentioned any restriction. You should state that in the question.

Comment: the values of the Hash can be either scalars or arrays

Comment: That is exactly the case with `{a: [[1], 2]}`.

Comment: mh, sorry, I meant scalars or arrays of scalars

Comment: Also, do you want the method to be destructive? That is, do you want it to change the original hash, or you want to make a copy of it?

Comment: Thanks, I would like it not to be destructive. I need a copy of the original hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
def remove_criterion key, value
  params.each_with_object({}) do |pair, h|
    k, v = *pair
    if k == key
      case v
      when Array
        nv = v.reject { |each| each == value }
        h[k] = nv unless nv.empty?
      else
        h[k] = v unless v == value
      end
    else
      h[k] = v
    end
  end
end
```

Testing it out in irb:

```
irb(main):007:0> remove_criterion :a, 1
=> {:b=>2, :c=>[9, 8, 7]}
irb(main):008:0> remove_criterion :c, 8
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[9, 7]}
irb(main):009:0> remove_criterion :a, 3
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[9, 8, 7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_criterion(key, value)
  params.each do |k,v| 
    if k == key and v == value
      params.delete(key)
    elsif v.class == Array and v.include?(value)
      v.delete(value)
    end
  end
  params
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
def doit(h,k,v)
  return h unless h.include?(k)
  if h[k] == v
    h.delete(k)
  elsif h[k].is_a? Array      
    h[k].delete(v)
  end
  h
end 

h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: [9, 8, 7]}

doit(h,:b,2) #  => {:a=>1,        :c=>[9, 8, 7]}
doit(h,:b,3) #  => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[9, 8, 7]} 
doit(h,:c,8) #  => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[9,    7]}
doit(h,:c,6) #  => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[9, 8, 7]} 
doit(h,:d,1) #  => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[9, 8, 7]}
```